# Trying to read a local file on page load in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I'm creating a web application that references a local txt (or csv) file which will change every year. I want to be able to load the contents of the file into a `<textarea>` on page startup.

Right now, I have functional code for loading the contents into a `<textarea>` by using the `<input>` element (thanks to a previous StackOverflow question in 2015). The file is selected and an event listener will call a function once the input state gets changed. My challenge is modifying the code so that the file can be hard-coded and loaded on startup and still calling the function using an event (or changing the function to work without an event call).

**index.html**

```html
    <input type="file" id="fileinput" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dataLoad.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
    </script>
    <textarea rows=20 id="area"></textarea>
```

**dataLoad.js**

```
function readSingleFile(evt) {
    //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
    var f = evt.target.files[0]; 
    if (f) {
        var r = new FileReader();
        r.onload = function(e) {
          var display = "";
          //a lot of unimportant stuff here
          document.getElementById('area').value = display;
        }

        r.readAsText(f);

    } else { 
        alert("Failed to load file");
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I don't want to manually select the file to load, I want to hard-code the file. The "a lot of unimportant stuff here" parses the data in the file so I left it out for clarity sake.

Comment: If you want to access the user's file system when the page loads, you cannot do that, if you want to hard code the contents of a file in your page and read it as a file, you can do that using a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)

Comment: @Titus exactly, I want to hard code the file in, and I think the current code uses a Blob. I'm not very familiar with it all though, so any advice would be nice!

Comment: Click the [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) word in this or my previous comment to see the documentation. There are a lot of examples on that page.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot due to security reasons.

You don't want the websites you visit to be able to do this, do you?

Try This:

```
 <object width="300" height="300" type="text/plain" data="password.txt" border="0" >
</object
```

Comment: I think I worded the question poorly. I don't want to access the user's file system. I want to pass through my own local file. I'll edit it for future responses

Comment: Then Use This <object width="300" height="300" type="text/plain" data="password.txt" border="0" >
</object> and design it as textarea

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the `<input type="file" />` has `autocomplete` on (which I believe it does by default), any files that were chosen/dragged onto the element should still be present on page load, so all you would need to do is manually trigger the `change` event that you added an `eventListener` for, like so:

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" />
<textarea rows=20 id="area"></textarea>

<script>
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileinput');
    var event     = new Event('change');

    fileInput.addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);

    fileInput.dispatchEvent(event);

    function readSingleFile(evt) {
        var f = evt.target.files[0];

        if (f) {
            alert("Processing file...");
        }
    }
</script>
```

This won't work in JSFiddle as it rebuilds the HTML when you refresh the page, however this works offline for me.

Comment: maybe I worded the question incorrectly. I don't want to use the `<input>` tag, I just want the file to be hard-coded and loaded on page start. Also tried what you suggested and got `index.html:36 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'.`